# java - Color Header not working

Tags: java, swing

I want to change color the header of my table and also i have already code of that. but it's nothing happen. this is my code.

```
public void setupcolor() {

    table_desc.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(51,122,183));
    table_desc.getTableHeader().setOpaque(false);
    table_desc.getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    table_desc.getTableHeader().setFont(new java.awt.Font("Noto Sans", 0, 14));

}
```

[see the screenshot, the header did not changes even my codes is right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efYoY.png)

Comment: Please add which framework you are using. More details we have, better support we can provide.

Comment: Add in tags if you are using AWT or Swing (or something else ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that not every "Look and feel" for AWT/Swing support the color change of table headers. If you want to use this feature, you'll have to use a Look and feel with this feature support. The "Java Default" Look and feel support this.

I think you are using the "System Default" Look and feel. This one does not support color change of table headers.

You find how to change the Look and feel at runtime here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html